# Open Chrome App with URL

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, android-browser

Is there a way to open Chrome app on Android from default Android browser? I'm able to open the app, but it doesn't redirect user to correct page. This is what I tried:

```
<a href="googlechrome://www.toovia.com">
```

I saw that I may have to form an intent URL, but I was hoping that there is a much easier way than that.

This is supposed to be from a web page and there is no web view involved.

Comment: Can this be done with a Javascript function or a script tag?

Comment: Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912296/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-trying-opening-googlechrome-navigateurl-xx

Answer (score 18):

Yes, but if it's not installed on the system you'll run into an ActivityNotFoundException. If it's not available, you should launch through the normal browser:

```
String url = "http://mysuperwebsite";
try {
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Chrome is not installed
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I actually need a URL since it's not an app. What does it look like then?

Comment: I can't help you with that, but having it as a normal URL should default to their selected browser or open up a chooser window (whichever they have selected) and is the normal process for Android.

Comment: Hi, I want to load a html page in chrome browser, but it is not rendering intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Test_4.html"));

Comment: How to do this with javascript ?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution without a `try catch,` if chrome is installed, it will be used. Otherwise, it will go to the device default

```
void open(Activity activity, String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    if (i.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) == null) {
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    }
    activity.startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best thing is to detect the user browser

```
alert(navigator.userAgent);
```

and depending on a conditional statement

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('foo')) {
 // code logic
}
```

and based on that use BOM API to update window location

```
window.location.href = 'googlechrome://navigate?url='+ link;
```

Comment: But I had a problem with this in Android, so did others....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912296/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-trying-opening-googlechrome-navigateurl-xx

Answer (score 2):

I opened my Safe Browser App with getting package name from Google play, the same way you can open for chrome by default also:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://Your URL"));
intent.setPackage("com.cloudacl");  // package of SafeBrowser App 
startActivity(intent);
```

You can replace package `com.cloudacl` with this `com.android.chrome` to open chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I am using below code to open **`Chrome browser`** from Android app

```
String urlString = "http://google.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
try
{
    context.startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
{
    //if Chrome browser not installed
    intent.setPackage(null);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android Kotlin**

> Try this below code for intent to chrome browser in kotlin.

```
val uri = Uri.parse("googlechrome://navigate?url="+"https://stackoverflow.com/")
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
if (i.resolveActivity(this@MainActivity.packageManager) == null) {
   i.data = Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/")
}
this@MainActivity.startActivity(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```java
try {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
   activity.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
   // chrome app not install
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Intent solutions above no longer seem to work.

The following works for me ..

document.location = 'googlechrome://navigate?url=www.tovia.com/';