# Android version check pop-up window

Tags: javascript, java, android, popup, smali

I'm writing java code for an android program, I'm stuck at the version check pop-up window, I want this pop-up to tell the users that their program is out of date and they need to update to the latest version.
And I want a button to redirect them to a ota.jason for them to find the new version.
Any ideas for the pop-up window functions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for know how to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase remote config (or API). Store the latest version code in firebase remote config (or server database) then compare the current version code of your app and server version code and show the dialog accordingly.

Comment: Yeah thanks about your recommendation, I will give it a shot. Do you have any idea about linking a button to a URL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255026/open-chrome-app-with-url