# Is there any new way to open fb in browser only?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to open the fb link in browser mode only in android. not want to trigger the app.

Tried all possible ways to resolve the solution but none of them work.

By default the web browser opens the app by default.

Is there a solution to solve this.I don't want to open the app

Answer (score 0):

If you just use a `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)` or similar, the OS will open the URL depending on whether any apps want to handle it ([more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)). This will typically open within Facebook's app since they have verified ownership of their domains, as you've discovered.

There are 2 main workarounds:

1. **Force the OS to open your link in a specific browser**. By manually passing your target URL to a browser ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255561/608312)), it *might* work. However, this is hacky, and may not even be possible depending on your app's permissions. You'd also have to consider every possible browser, which is not realistic.
2. **Use an embedded WebView**. Instead of asking the OS to handle the link, you can instead embed a mini-browser in your app. This is recommended, and how most apps solve the issue. [Here is the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview#AddingWebView), make sure to consider whether JavaScript should run, how links should work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not well versed in tech, but mbasic.facebook.com still works for me, even in a Google tab. Another way is to use an incognito tab inside the Chrome browser. I have Android too.

Comment: This isn't really answers the question. Can you maybe add some information to the answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35619548)